# Read files that are pipe AND comma delimited: |column1|,|column2|

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I have files that look like this:

```
|2000|,|23456745|,|23567897tyhgy6|,|SHARP, RODNEY H III|
|2000|,|12345678|,|34567tgh788877|,|WOOLARD, EDGAR S JR|
```

Basically, the columns are separated by commas and wrapped by pipes.

How do I read something like this using R?

I have tried

```
read.table("file.txt", sep="|")
```

but this doesn't work well, since every other column just contains a comma. I have tried using "|,|" as the separator, but apparently this is not allowed. Using "," doesn't work at all since the names then get split up.

Any easy way to do this?

Comment: try `read.table("./temp.csv", sep=",", quote = "|")`

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the suggested topic.. this question is not about multiple separators..

Comment: @Wimpel your idea worked great, very fast too! If you post it as an answer, I will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read.table("./temp.csv", sep=",", quote = "|")` will do the trick...

Answer (score 1):

You can just try to replace it with other seperator:

```
plouf <-   readChar("file.txt", file.info("file.txt")$size)
plouf <- gsub("\\|,\\|",";",plouf) # replace the separator
plouf <- gsub("\\|","",plouf) # remove the end pipes
read.table(plouf,sep=";") # read with the semi colon sep
```

A test:

```
plouf <- "|2000|,|23456745|,|23567897tyhgy6|,|SHARP, RODNEY H III|
          |2000|,|12345678|,|34567tgh788877|,|WOOLARD, EDGAR S JR|"

plouf <- gsub("\\|,\\|",";",plouf)
plouf <- gsub("\\|","",plouf)
read.table(text = plouf,sep=";")

    V1       V2             V3                  V4
1 2000 23456745 23567897tyhgy6 SHARP, RODNEY H III
2 2000 12345678 34567tgh788877 WOOLARD, EDGAR S JR
```

Comment: The problem with this is that then "|Smith, John|" will be read as two columns...

Comment: @jackson5 I proposed an other solution

Comment: Thanks, this works as well. It is very slow on a large dataset, however.